# RabbitMQ single message per user possible?

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, google-kubernetes-engine

Brand new to rabbitMQ but considering using it as a queuing mechanism in GKE.   I have a question that is probably pretty easy.

Is there a way to only process a single message from a user (GUID in my application) at a given time (even if I have multiple workers).   Essentially, I have some upstream 3rd parties that POST to one of my endpoints duplicate messages.  I can confirm if there is already a duplicate document POSTed if I work syncronously (per user).   The issue arises if I have multiple worker nodes processing separate messages for the same user at the same time.

Is this possible in RabbitMQ?  Is there a recommended way to handle this?    Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with multiple workers consuming from the same queue. Either have a single worker, ensure that processing messages is idempotent, or coordinate between your workers.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is what I found as well.